# recursive function in NodeJS to check file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to build a function in NodeJS which recursively check whether it is file or directory using `fs` library to infinitely deep sub-directories, my code is something like this:

```
function generateComponents(path) {

    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach((file) => {
        if(fs.existsSync(file) && fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
            generateComponents(path+'/'+file);
        }
        else {
            //Do some code
        }
    });

}
```

It works for first folder/directory but when it goes for next directory it accepts as files and condition goes into else part. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is it windows as path separator is `/` better use `path.join`

Comment: @AZ_ it 's just the string concatenation part which I'll be using to write a file at later stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that `file` in your code is JUST a filename.  To recurse you have to recombine the filename with the path in order to call generateComponents in a directory that's different than the original path.  That includes when you call `fs.existsSync()` and `fs.lstatSync()`:

```
const path = require('path');

function generateComponents(dir) {
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((file) => {
        let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
        if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
            console.log(`directory: ${fullPath}`)
            generateComponents(fullPath);
        } else {
            console.log(`filename: ${fullPath}`)
            //Do some code
        }
    });
}
```

FYI, you should also use the `withFileTypes` option for `fs.readdirSync()` as that will save you the `fs.lstatSync()` call and the `fs.existsSync()` call is entirely unnecessary.  `fs.readdirSync()` just told you the file was there, you don't have to check if it's there again.

That simplified version using `withFileTypes` would look like this:

```
const path = require('path');

function generateComponents(dir) {
    fs.readdirSync(dir, {withFileTypes: true}).forEach((entry) => {
        let fullPath = path.join(dir, entry.name);
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            console.log(`directory: ${fullPath}`)
            generateComponents(fullPath);
        } else if (entry.isFile()) {
            //Do some code with fullPath file
            console.log(`filename: ${fullPath}`)
        } else {
            // apparently there are some other things that could be here
            // like a symlink, so this is defensive coding
            console.log(`unexpected type: ${fullPath}`);
        }
    });
}
```